# How to upload a file from a URL as multipart/form-data in Postman

Tags: postman

I have an API endpoint that accepts `multipart/form-data` file upload. I managed to upload a local file to it with Postman using the `File` option as below:

[image: Postman request body screenshot]

Now how can I upload a file that is hosted at a given URL using Postman without manually downloading it and then selecting its filename as in the above screenshot? I'm hoping to somehow `GET` the URL, store the binary data, and upload to the endpoint, all within a Postman collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the answers from [Postman community issue](https://community.postman.com/t/post-a-file-from-a-url/27739/3):

> Using [Postman’s pre-request script](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/pre-request-scripts/):
>
> 1. Download the content from URL
> 2. Convert it to binary
> 3. Assign the binary value to a dynamic variable
> 4. Use the variable within your request